$G$ be a topological group, $F$ be compact such that $F \subset U$, $U$ open in $G$, then there is a nbd $V$ of $e$ such that $FV \cup VF \subset U$.
Let $G$ be a topological group with identity $e$, $F$ be a compact subset of $G$ such that $F \subset U$, where $U$ is an open in $G$, then there is a neighborhood $V$ of $e$ such that $FV \cup VF \subset U$.
Proof :
Let $x \in F \subset U$, since $U$ is open there is $V_x$ and $W_x$ neighborhood of $e$ such that $xV_x \subset U$ and $W_xx \subset U.$
Then $V_x \cap W_x$ is a neighborhood of $e$.
There exist a symmetric neighborhood $Z_x$ of $e$ such that $Z_x^2 \subset V_x \cap W_x.$ Since $F$ is compact, $F \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} x_iZ_{x_i}$.
Put $V= \cap_{i=1}^{n} x_iZ_{x_i}$
Then we obtain $FV \subset U$. I need $VF \subset U$ to conclude that $FV \cup VF \subset U$.
If $y=vf$ where $v \in V, f \in F$, then for any $i, v \in Z_{x_i}$ and for some $j, f \in x_jZ_{x_j}$. So $vf \in Z_{x_j}x_jZ_{x_j}$, from here how can I say that $vf \in U?$
